# I made a webhook using snippet plugin, but is not working

Tags: rest-api

I'm trying to make a POST request webhook using the snippet plugin, I will paste the code shortly, but first:

- Does using snippet a viable option to make a webhook?
- Is it **required** that the end point has a key/password?
- Is there any "calling" of that snippet that it needs in order for it to work correctly?

Now the code I wrote is this:

```php
function subscribe($order_id)
{
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $billingEmail = $order->billing_email;
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_email = $current_user->user_email;
    $products = $order->get_items();
    $period = -5;

    foreach ($products as $prod) {
        $product_name = $prod->get_name();
        if ($product_name == '1 month subscription') {
            $period += 6;
            $url = 'https://url:myport/end/point';
        } elseif ($product_name == '3 months subscription') {
            $period += 8;
            $url = 'https://url:myport/end/point';
        }
    }
    $body = array('email' => $user_email, 'subscription_period' => $period,);

    if ($period > -3) {
        wp_remote_post($url, array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'timeout' => 10,
            'redirection' => 10,
            'sslverify' => false,
            'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8',),
            'body' => json_encode($body)));
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status_completed', 'subscribe');
```

Do you see anything wrong with it?
Is there something missing?
I tried it, but it never sent a POST request to my web app.
NOTE : I didn't use the graphical version that is in woo->settings because I didn't make a secret/bearer string to my endpoint, I know I should, maybe I'll do it later.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to debug this. I'd start by adding lots of error_log() calls to the code: you want to trace that the subscribe function has been called, the $product_name and total $period value for each product so you can see if the -3 threshold is hit, that you're calling wp_remote_post and also what the return value of wp_remote_post is, so you can see if it's returning you a WP_Error object. I'd also trace at the top level of the snippet to make sure it's being run in the first place, but you can remove that as soon as you've verified it as the trace will fire for every request.

Comment: Whether that's the right action to hook though, and whether you're fetching the woocommerce data correctly, is probably something you should ask WooCommerce directly - you'll find more expertise there than here. Ditto any questions about the snippet plugin (you haven't told us which) should probably go to the authors of that. FWIW I'd write a simple plugin of my own rather than using a snippet plugin, but I realise these are simpler to get started with.

Comment: OK, I will start adding logs.. but, can I "print" those variables as I can do on a regular computer terminal ? Plus , what do you mean with "top level" ... As for the snippet that I use, it's mentioned on the WC website. here it is: "https://woo.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/" ... and the action is also from their action trigger list.

Comment: I should tell you that I made advances, now the same code is sending POST requests, I did that by adding x and y int to ' add_action( 'trigger', 'function' , x , y); ' ... I think y was the big deal, it's the number of variables that are input to the function, in my case 1 ...
 my problem now is that I'm getting "Unprocessable Entity" , so I should now debug the variables and their values... but Thanks a llot for your time, I will start debugging now.